# Setting Home Directory for newly added users

Tags: powershell, users, home-directory

I'm writing a Powershell script to do a complete Windows 7 Build.  I have a function that adds the users I need, but it does not set the Home Directory, which makes a later section of my script (setting the users' desktops) fail because the directories "don't exist" yet.

Here is the main part of the function:

```
 [CmdletBinding()] 
 Param( 
  [Parameter(Position=0, 
      Mandatory=$True, 
      ValueFromPipeline=$True)] 
  [string]$userName, 
  [Parameter(Position=1, 
      Mandatory=$True, 
      ValueFromPipeline=$True)] 
  [string]$password, 
  [string]$computerName = $env:ComputerName, 
  [string]$description = "Created by PowerShell" 
 ) 
 $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName" 
 $user = $computer.Create("User", $userName) 
 $user.setpassword($password) 
 $user.put("description",$description)  
 $user.SetInfo() 
} #end function New-LocalUser
```

Is there somewhere in there to add something akin to **$user.put("HomePath","\Users\automotive\Desktop")** for example so that it doesn't break the later part of my script.

---

Here is the code I'm using in my Users.cmd script:

Here's the code in my .cmd file:

```
SETLOCAL 

SET Profile=C:\Users
SET user=cars
SET password=cars

SET PSEXEC="C:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite\PsExec.exe" 
SET wmic=%windir%\System32\Wbem\WMIC

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%I IN ('REG QUERY ^"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList^" /v ProfilesDirectory^|find /i ^"ProfilesDirectory^"') DO (SET ProfilesDirectory=%%J) 
@echo ProfilesDirectory: %ProfilesDirectory% 

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfilesDirectory /t REG_SZ /d "%Profile%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Systinternals\PsExec" /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

NET USER /add %user% %password% /comment:"Account for User" /expires:never /homedir:%Profile%\%user% 
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators /add %user%
%PSEXEC% -h -u %user% -p %password% "%wmic% QUIT"

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfilesDirectory /t REG_SZ /d "%ProfilesDirectory%" /f
```

I call it with this command, followed by my commands to create the new Desktop.

```
\Windows\System32\cmd /c c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Users.cmd -wait

Remove-Item \Users\cars\Desktop -recurse -force
Copy-Item E:\"Desktop Cars" C:\Users\cars Desktop -recurse
```

The DOS commands run by fine until it gets to

```
%PSEXEC% -h -u %user% -p %password% "%wmic% QUIT"
```

That is followed by all of this in red before it gets to the final REG ADD command -

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite\PsExec.exe"  -h -u cars -p cars "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\WMIC QUIT" 
cmd.exe : 
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktops.ps1:3 char:22
+ \Windows\System32\cmd <<<<  /c c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Users.cmd -wait
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


The system cannot find the file specified.

Connecting to local system...Starting PsExec service on local system...Connecting with PsExec service on ccm2756...Starting C:\Windows\
System32\Wbem\WMIC QUIT on ccm2756...
PsExec could not start C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\WMIC QUIT on ccm2756:
```

After that, it has added the account and the commands to change the Desktop work, but the files for the User's Desktop are "in use" until I reboot the system.

Comment: Their user/desktop folder won't come into existence until they log in for the first time.

Comment: Exactly techie007 - I'm looking for a way to bring those folders into existence using Powershell (the build is all in one script).  This is one of the few snags I've run into so far.  I'm thinking it may be related to the "\Users\Default" directory that already exists on the system, but I'm not sure how to use that nor implement it with Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Add user and set Home Directory at local:

```
NET USER UserName DerParol /add /comment:"Account for User" /expires:never /homedir:C\Acc\UserName
```

Add user at local Administrators group.

```
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators /add UserName
```

## `PSexec` part of [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Create User Profile,

## proinit.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET Profile=C:\Acc
SET user=Troll
SET password=DerParol

SET PSEXEC="C:\Program Files\SysinternalsSuite\PSEXEC"
SET wmic=%windir%\system32\wbem\wmic

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%I IN ('REG QUERY ^"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList^" /v ProfilesDirectory^|find /i ^"ProfilesDirectory^"') DO (
SET ProfilesDirectory=%%J)
@echo ProfilesDirectory: %ProfilesDirectory%

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfilesDirectory /t REG_SZ /d "%Profile%" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\PsExec" /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

NET USER /add %user% %password% /comment:"Account for User" /expires:never /homedir:%Profile%\%user% /profilepath:%Profile%\%user%
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators /add %user%
%PSEXEC% -h -u %user% -p %password% "%wmic% QUIT"

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /v ProfilesDirectory /t REG_SZ /d "%ProfilesDirectory%" /f
```

[image: Test <code>net user</code> command]

Domain, use: `dsadd user`

```
@ECHO OFF
@SET user=UserName
@SET password=DerParole

@SET pwdSet=-canchpwd yes -pwdneverexpires yes
::-mustchpwd yes

@SET accSet=-disabled no -acctexpires never -upn %user%@%USERDNSDOMAIN% -samid %user%
@SET dirSet=-profile \\SERV\Acc\%user% -hmdrv R: -hmdir \\SERV\Acc\%user% -loscr enver.cmd
@SET Brand=-office "Grand-1" -company TT -dept HT -title MegaUser
@SET locSet=-tel 914-55-04-42 -email %user%II@%USERDNSDOMAIN% -webpg %user%.%USERDNSDOMAIN% 
@SET callIn=-hometel 9-slip-010-292 -pager 1022 -mobile "8(777) 101-44-22" -fax "977-101-44-22" -iptel 6002
@SET nameSt=-fn User -ln Name -mi "U.N." -display "UserName II"
@SET Description=-desc "Account for User"

::@SET cmSet=@ECHO dsadd user
@SET cmSet=dsadd user

@For /F %%a In ('dsquery * -filter "(objectCategory=domain)"') Do @SET dc=%%a

@SET dn="cn=%user%,cn=users,%dc:~1%
::@SET grpSet=-memberof "cn=ResourceGroup,cn=users,%dc:~1%

%cmSet% -pwd %password% %dn% %pwdSet% %accSet% %dirSet% %Brand% %locSet% %callIn% %nameSt% %Description% -uc

dsquery *  -filter "(samAccountName=%user%)" -attr * | more
```

dsadd user test batch script:

[image: dsadd user test batch script]

## Bulk Import CSVDE.

## See: [Step-by-Step Guide to Bulk Import and Export to Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727091.aspx)

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the NET USER /add command, STTR.  It adds it as a Standard account and I need to add it as an Administrator account and (at least so far) I haven't found an option for adding it as such.  Secondly, I've tested the NET USER /add command and then run a "md \Users\username", but as soon as I login as that user, it creates a whole other directory as "\Users\username.computername\". Need to find a way to set this so copy commands will work later in the script.

Comment: @BigRedEO `net localgroup Administrators /add UserName` Not need  `"md \Users\username"`

Comment: That will add a user to the Administrators group, thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem of the home directory of each user not being created until that user is first logged in.  I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the "Default" directory found in "\Users"?  In other words, when you first login to a new account and it says "Preparing your desktop", what is actually running there to prepare the desktop.  Could that give me what I need to activate the users Home directory?

Comment: @BigRedEO What you want - `Profile Path`. Then what was asked - `Home Directory`. Understand exactly what you need.

Comment: @BigRedEO Updated, test script `proinit.cmd`.

Comment: THANK YOU.  After several stops/starts because of typos (such as a capital "S" needed on "System32" and whitespace in a couple places, got it all to work - except one command fails.  I get

`PsExec could not start C:\Windows\System32\wbec\wmic  QUIT on computername
The system could not find the path specified`

I know the path exists - I had to search for wmic since it wasn't under \Windows\System, but under \Windows\System32 instead and I changed my code accordingly.  However, it still adds the account, home directory and profile path, which has allowed my desktop changes to work.

Comment: NEVER MIND!  Found my typo in the path!  Testing again!

Comment: I now have the correct path, but now I'm getting - `"The system cannot find the file specified."`  - I even put it exactly as it is in our system - `WMIC.exe` - and still get the file error.

Comment: @BigRedEO `powershell gcm wmic` or `where wmic` ?

Comment: That does tell me that PsExec IS located in the directory I have in my code, but still not quite right.  I'm having to put the code in a .cmd script (since some of the commands don't work directly in Powershell) and it IS working, but it's still throwing out errors and not shutting down PsExec until after a reboot.  I'll have to post my .cmd script and the specific errors I'm getting.

Comment: See edited changes and error above.

Comment: @STTR: Thank you, this is solid gold. You made my day!